# Combine PDF and Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, carrierwave, prawn

I am using the prawn gem to generate a pdf of my model attributes. I have had no issues with this thus far. However, I am now using Carrierwave to upload additional PDFs for reference.

Carrierwave works as expected, as my model has the following change when uploading an additional PDF:

```
documents: [] to [{"url"=>"/uploads/tmp/1536259407-12025-0001-8255/Amazon.com_-_Order_111-4655889-4409816.pdf"}]
```

I would like to render the attached carrierwave pdf (`document`) to my rendered prawn PDF using the combine_pdf gem.

My controller has the following code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.js
  format.json
  format.pdf do
    order_pdf = OrderPdf.new(@order, current_user).render
    final_pdf = CombinePDF.new 
    final_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(order_pdf)
    if @order.documents.any? 
      @order.documents.each do |doc|
        # if I comment out this line, the original pdf loads, as expected 
        final_pdf << CombinePDF.parse(IO.read(doc.url))
      end 
    end 
    send_data final_pdf.to_pdf,
              filename: "order_#{@order.id}.pdf",
              type: 'application/pdf',
              disposition: 'inline'
  end
end
```

I am getting an `Errno::ENOENT` error (or a timeout):

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /uploads/order/documents/16/Amazon.com_-_Order_111-4655889-4409816.pdf
```

For reference here is my DocumentUploader:

```
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
```